# Flash Alchemy built .swc library too small and missing functions

Tags: flash, actionscript, g++, swc, alchemy

I can modify and compile the SDK's stringecho.c example for AS3 use no problem.

For my own app, I compile with g++ a few dozen files successfully and link:

```
g++ -swc -o myApp.swc glue.o demo.o obj1.o obj2.o obj3.o
```

I do get a myApp.swc, but it's erroneously only 80k (same size as the simple stringecho example).

When examined in any flash IDE, unlike the stringecho.swc which has

```
cmodule.stringecho.AlchemyBlock 
cmodule.stringecho.AlchemyBreakPoint
...
```

This myApp.swc has

```
cmodule.AlchemyBlock
cmodule.AlchemyBreakPoint
...
```

And has no glue function I defined. In essence, I can't use it in an AS3 project.

My glue.c code is below. Basically, I create a demo object and call its functions. The demo class encapsulates all the other object files.

```
#include "demo.h"
#include "AS3.h"
    AS3_Val InitSystem(void* self, AS3_Val args)
    {
        demo = new demo9();
        return 0;
    }

    AS3_Val LoadSceneFile( void* self, AS3_Val args )
    {
        demo->loadScene("scene.txt");
        return 0;
    }

...

    int main()
    {
        AS3_Val InitSystemMethod = AS3_Function( NULL, InitSystem );
        AS3_Val LoadSceneFileMethod = AS3_Function( NULL, LoadSceneFile );
        AS3_Val getAlchemyScreenMethod = AS3_Function( NULL, getAlchemyScreen );
        AS3_Val setMouseStateMethod = AS3_Function( NULL, setMouseState );
        AS3_Val rasterizeMethod = AS3_Function( NULL, rasterize );

        AS3_Val result = AS3_Object("InitSystem: AS3ValType,LoadSceneFile: AS3ValType,getAlchemyScreen:AS3ValType,setMouseState:AS3ValType,rasterize:AS3ValType"
                                    ,InitSystemMethod,
                                    LoadSceneFileMethod,
                                    getAlchemyScreenMethod,
                                    setMouseStateMethod,
                                    rasterizeMethod);

        AS3_Release( InitSystemMethod );
        AS3_Release( LoadSceneFileMethod );
        AS3_Release( getAlchemyScreenMethod );
        AS3_Release( setMouseStateMethod );
        AS3_Release( rasterizeMethod );

        AS3_LibInit( result );

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Read this [blog post](http://ccgi.codegadget.plus.com/blog/category/alchemy/).

The short story is that linking lots of .o files won't work.  You need to 'ar' them together into a library (.a) file.  Then you compile your glue code against that library.  Per your example it would be something like this:

```
ar rc mylib.a demo.o obj1.o obj2.o obj3.o
ranlib mylib.a
g++ -swc -o myApp.swc glue.c mylib.a
```

Comment: was this helpful to you? if so, please accept my response as the answer